# Including environment variables in docker run with bundled javascript

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Dockerfile that builds a https://vuejs.org/ application, and then in a second stage puts it behind an nginx load balancer:

```
  1 # builds a production image of website
  2 
  3 FROM node:alpine AS builder
  4 
  5 WORKDIR /tmp/build/
  6 COPY . .
  7 
  8 CMD ["npm", "install"]
  9 CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
 10 
 11 
 12 FROM nginx:1.19.0 AS application
 13 
 14 COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 15 COPY --from=builder /tmp/build/dist /var/app
```

I'm running this Dockerfile on Kubernetes, which I want to use to provide environment variables to my Pods running this image.

### Problem

With javascript builds, environment variables are actually just hardcoded into the bundle during build time (so, line 9 in the Dockerfile). Because running this image will generally mean that we've passed this step, I miss the opportunity to put the environment variable into the build.

### Question

How can I force the entire Dockerfile to rebuild *with Kubernetes* for each new Pod, so I can insert the current environment into the build? With docker I can just use the --no-cache flag, but I'm not sure what the corresponding thing would be for Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1):

> environment variables are actually just hardcoded into the bundle during build time

A very common nodejs problem -- [react-env](https://github.com/andrewmclagan/react-env#readme) is one approach, whereby the app changes to stop asking for `process.env` over to `env('something')` which resolves to `window.__env__` (or whatever) that is populated by an XHR to `/env.js`, which is itself written out by the container on startup

You may want add a [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) tag to your question, to find out how they are solving this problem, since it's actually not a docker nor a kubernetes problem, really